# Error in web connector when quickbooks not running

Tags: soap, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, ipp-qbd-sync

I am using web connector with my application to integrate with quickbooks desktop. All things run fine when quickbooks is running but when quickbooks is not running i get the following error:

**20140820.15:43:08 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
20140820.15:43:08 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20140820.15:43:08 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20140820.15:43:08 UTC    : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
If the QuickBooks company data file is not open, a call to the "BeginSession" method must include the name of the data file.**

I am sending the company data file path in authenticate response but still getting this error even when i selected the option "Yes Always; allow access even if quickbooks is not running" and the auto login in quickbooks company preferences is also checked.

I searched for this error and found the following links

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1145/errors-in-qsc-intuit-quickbooks-integration-last-connection-log

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1150/configuring-intuit-quickbooks-to-accept-automatic-logins

but when i checked quickbooks it was already set for auto login from the app.

Please suggest any solution for this error.

Comment: You might need to enable verbose logging in the QBWC and SDK and see if the file name is being passed when the connection starts.

https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/177198-troubleshooting-sdk-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve this issue which was due to a silly mistake. The file path was "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Intuit/QuickBooks/sample Company Files/QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0/sample_manufacturing business.qbw" which i was sending whereas it should have been "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Sample Company Files\QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0\sample_manufacturing business.QBW" for windows system.

A silly thing to have done and ignored :).

Finally got it right. **Thanks William**