# QB Desktop PHP integration via web-connector on system having multiple company files

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

```
QB desktop 2021 Enterprise version,
Multi-user mode not enabled,
qwc: Quickbooks Web connector
```

I am using Consolibyte's PHP sdk to connect QB desktop with our CMS. I am pulling some accounting reports from the QB desktop. My concern is that we have some 10 different company files (10 different clients). I need to pull the report for each client so I have prepared 10 QWC connections i.e one for each company file. My concern is that I cannot set Auto-Run for each web-connector setting (despite of having a gap of 1 hour between each entry). While installing qwc file, I have set automatically open the company file if not open("Always allow access even if Quickbooks is not running") but I keep on getting below error message when ever Auto-run tries to execute the configured app. I get the same error even if I do not open the QB company file in the QB and tries to run the same manually

```
Application requested to Abort
```

If I open up the company file in QB and then select the qwc application and select "update selected" then it works fine.

This is creating concern as I am not able to run the qwc apps automatically and have to run it manually. I will be having 50 company files and running it manually is time consuming. Can anyone please guide me as why it needs the company file to open prior running the web-connector (then what is the use of selecting ("Always allow access even if Quickbooks is not running")) and in that case automatic execution of qwc app not possible as somebody has to open the company file first. Kindly guide

Answer (score 0):

Adand,

I had faced similar problem with consilbyte SDK for QBD web connector integration.

Sometime the problem is that QBD services are running in background and connected to one of the company, which we don't know where.

so in order to reset all things and try once again, you should kill following services which are running in your windows PC. and then start all company sync in web connector.

[image]

[image]

This should solve your problem. if not then share the web connector log file. so i can investigate and provide solution.

additionally you should try these solutions specific to Web Connector https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/help-article/open-programs/fix-common-web-connector-errors-quickbooks-desktop/L9slolvg0_US_en_US

Comment: Thanks Chintan but killing QB processes is not a solution. It can cause data corruption, company file damage etc as there are background services which we do not know when and how updates data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for problem. Issue was that when we have multiple company files and if we want QWC to open up the right company file automatically then we have to set the **company file path** for each QWC user in the QB table (Consolibyte PHP SDK) "quickbooks_user"

```
UPDATE quickbooks_user SET qb_company_file = 'C:\path\to\your\file.QBW' WHERE qb_username = 'your-web-connector-username'
```

I have found this answer through below stackoverflow threads

[Error in web connector when quickbooks not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419586/error-in-web-connector-when-quickbooks-not-running)
[How to set .QBW file path for response in Authenticate for Quickbooks Web Connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293226/how-to-set-qbw-file-path-for-response-in-authenticate-for-quickbooks-web-connec)

and from Wiki pages by Keith/Consolibyte:
http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte#how_can_i_tell_the_web_connector_to_connect_to_quickbooks_even_if_quickbooks_is_not_open

I have tried this and it works. QB company file is opened up in background by QWC, data pulled and then company file is closed by QWC. I am hopeful that this inbuilt solution will allow me to automate 50+ QWC executions.